# Move activity to background in broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, background-process

Is this possible to move activity to background in broadcast receiver?
Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            Intent i = new Intent(context, Login.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
            //I want to move above activity to background
        }
    }
```

Is this possible to do? I googled it, but I couldn't find right answer.
Thanks for any help ;-)

Solution: It is better to start intent service from broadcast receiver instead of start activity and move it to background. Thanks @Mike M.

Comment: Why would you want to start an Activity, only to hide it immediately? Are you sure you need an Activity? Maybe a Service instead?

Comment: I don't know, why I didn't thought about this ;-) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure thing. Also, judging from the name you have for the Activity class, an IntentService might be a good fit. They're generally easier to implement and initiate.